# Why doesn't this basic Jquery audio code fire in Android 4.2 (jellybean's) chrome browser

Tags: jquery

I've got some JQuery code that works fine in Chrome and Firefox on the desktop, but does not work when I test it in chrome on a galaxy Nexus 10. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                        var babySpeech = document.createElement('audio');
                        babySpeech.setAttribute('src', 'myurlishere');
                        babySpeech.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
                        babySpeech.addEventListener("load", function() {
                            babySpeech.play();
                        }, true);
                    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UWHYG/5/

Comment: `$.get();` is meaningless

Comment: Edited, anyone got any ideas why this code wont fire in chrome for android?

Comment: what format is the audio?

Comment: I don't think the audio tag works on mobile devices.

Comment: It's MP3, the audio tag does work, because it works if I change $(document).ready to $(document).click, and I click the page.  I cant use this behaviour though I need the audio to play on page load.

Comment: Still stumped on this :-/